# Changing Device Input for Web speech Api:

Tags: javascript, angular, speech-recognition, getusermedia, webspeech-api

Is there a way to change the Microphone input for the Web speech api?

For getUserMedia() we can do setSinkId(deviceId) to set the desired microphone, but for the webSpeech how to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Appears not: https://github.com/WICG/speech-api/issues/66. Confirmed there is nothing mentioned in the spec: https://wicg.github.io/speech-api/.